# How to check that activity displays dialog during android unit testing

Tags: android, unit-testing, testing, junit

I want to write testcases for my android application using JUnit.
And I faced some problems.

Is it possible to check that activity displays some dialog at current moment?
Here is a small piece of my test application:

```
    ...
    Instrumentation instr = getInstrumentation();
    monitor = instr.addMonitor(MainActivity.class.getName(), null, false);
    /* Click on login button */
    TouchUtils.clickView(this, mLoginButton);
    /* wait MainActivity */
    mMainActivity = instr.waitForMonitorWithTimeout(monitor, 3);
    assertNotNull(mMainActivity); 
    /* Here a want to check that progress dialog displayed on mMainActivity */
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at **Robotium** 
*'a open-source test framework created to make automatic black-box testing of Android applications significantly faster and easier than what is possible with Android instrumentation tests out-of-the-box.'*

Homepage: 
http://www.robotium.org/
Source:
http://github.com/jayway/robotium

*Please note that the Robotium project is maintained by the company I work for*

Comment: Jonas, thank you! I try to use your framework and it's greate! But unfortunately our company policy forbid to use any 3rd party components in our tests :(

Comment: Check the code for Robotium, it's open source. Maybe you can find something there that can help you.

Comment: Jonas, is it possible to check that some toast appeared on current activity using robotium?

Comment: Hi Evgeny. Try using searchText, but note that it's case sensitive. If you have more robotium questions check out Robotium Google Group http://groups.google.com/group/robotium-developers